Why am I receiveing this collation error in .NET Framework 4.5?
Currently I am analyzing old solutions in my company and it we get following error message randomly:
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "CreateXMLFile":System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException: Two strings to be concatenated have different collation.System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException:at System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString.op_Addition(SqlString x, SqlString y)at spCreateFile.FileCreator.CreateFile(SqlString FilePath, SqlXml Data, SqlString& ErrorMessage).

The function itself is saved as sql assembly, the source code is:
XML source code
We use sql SP to gather the needed data and just simply use CreateXMLFile to create so it's pretty basic. Below is the final part of our SP in sql:
Declare @xmlData xml
        set @xmlData = (select * from @ParametersFortable for xml path('Parameter'), root('ParametersCollection'))
 
        DECLARE @Directory nvarchar(max)
        Declare @TimeStamp nvarchar(200) = (SELECT format(getdate(),'yyyyMMddHHmmssffff')) 
        SET @Directory = 'C:\Path'+ @TimeStamp +'.xml'
         SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
         BEGIN TRY
                IF ISNULL(@Param1, '') <> '' AND ISNULL(@Param2, '') <> ''
                    execute @Status = CreateXMLFile @Directory, @xmlData, @ErrorMessage OUTPUT
         END TRY
         BEGIN CATCH
             SET @Status = ERROR_NUMBER();
             SET @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE();
             update Interface_Log
             set ErrorMessage = @ErrorMessage
             where id = @LogID;
         END CATCH;

The error you saw at the beggining it's being set in this CATCH above.
What is even more odd that if we try to create XML based on the same data twice it will always work the second time and my understanding is that it should either always work or never.
We use this assembly in many of our stored procedures but only one seems not to work properly.
We have this kind of error for almost a few years but previously it has been like 1 for a few months and now it's about few a day so it's seems more frustrating.
My guess it's now the system is overall more overloaded so that's why the frequency changed but it's only my assumption.
The only thing I have managed to confirm that for the same data we collect in our SP we generate the same xmlData, the data is always there and directory path is correct. It's only the result that is different, either error or success.

Why are you trying to create files directly from TSQL anyway? It's not a generalized scripting language, don't abuse it. Just do Powershell or something, eg Invoke-SqlCmd  ... | Out-File .... Anyway, looks like your issue is the catch block is concatenating the SqlString without using ToString() first.

Please don't post images of code or data, only paste text

Can you see which row the error is at in that C# code?
